# How do I stop speaker-test from running using python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've tried to google solutions but have not come up with any yet. If anyone thinks of something it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("speaker-test -t sine -f" + frequency, shell = True)
```

If I use only these two simple lines of code in python then the number given in variable frequency will run at that frequency forever. I want to be able to stop the speaker-test frequency from running after a certain amount of seconds. So what is the command to stop speaker-test?

Comment: I would frankly assume that nobody really understands your question. Furthermore, this community helps you to locate problems and find solutions with your given code - you should not expect that people start writing code for you from scratch. So, please elaborate...

Comment: @nostradamus Sorry, I now added more info that should help in answering the quesiton.

Comment: No idea what you "subprocess" module is, where did you get that from?  You'll probably have to dig into that one to determine what options you have for .call()

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my own problem. speaker-test has a parameter -l which determines how many loops of a particular frequency you would like to test. Playing around with some math I found that dividing the duration entered by 2.85 means one cycle is ~1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess  

subprocess.call("(speaker-test -t sine -f 200 -c 2 -Dhw:ALSA)& pid=$!; sleep 0.15; kill -9 $pid", shell = True)
```

this line worked in stopping the speaker-test for 0.15s